# AngularJS - how to not display HTML element until the variable it is binded to is loaded in the JS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This is my HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-hide="ctrl.userProfile.following">Follow</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-show="ctrl.userProfile.following">Unfollow</button>
```

So basically, I want to hide the "Follow" button and show the "Unfollow" button if `ctrl.userProfile.following` is `true`, and vise-versa.

This is my back-end:

```
self.userProfile = {};

function fetchUserProfile() {
    $http.get('/users/' + username)
    .then(function(response) {
        self.userProfile = response.data;
    }, function(response) {
        self.cerrorMessages = BaseService.accessErrors(response.data);
    });
};

fetchUserProfile();
```

So I get the `userProfile` and then update `self.userProfile` with the `watching` variable (this occurs when I do `self.userProfile = response.data`. With that said, is there a way for me to tell HTML to not display the buttons until `self.userProfile` is filled with `watching` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `userProfile.ready` flag and use that to control the showing of the `Follow` and `Unfollow` buttons.

HTML

```
<div ng-show="ctrl.userProfile.ready">
    <button type="button" ng-hide="ctrl.userProfile.following">Follow</button>
    <button type="button" ng-show="ctrl.userProfile.following">Unfollow</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
self.userProfile = {};
self.userProfile.ready = false;

function fetchUserProfile() {
    self.userProfile.ready = false;
    $http.get('/users/' + username)
      .then(function(response) {
         self.userProfile = response.data;
         self.userProfile.ready = true;
      }, function(error) {
         self.cerrorMessages = BaseService.accessErrors(error.data);
      });
};

fetchUserProfile();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways of doing this. Here is one:

If you start with an empty object, and are waiting for the promise to resolve, you can set a scope variable that checks the length of the object.

e.g.
self.userProfileLength = Object.keys(self.userProfile).length;

And in the view, do: ng-if="ctrl.userProfileLength"
(Note: Or use ng-show if you want to keep the element in the DOM)

Object.keys returns the keys from the object in an array. Anything over a length of 0 is a truthy value so it will pass the ng-if condition.

Comment: @ismcutler so you're saying I place the two buttons in a container `div` which has the `ng-if` statement? And then after the `GET` request has been complete and I update `self.userProfile` / give it a length, that's when the container `div` will be shown?

Comment: @user2719875 you can place it on a container or directly on the buttons themselves. The length will be calculated automatically when the call is resolved successfully once you assign the response to the instance variable (userProfile).

Comment: Right. But if I do `ng-if="ctrl.userProfileLength"` (or `ng-show` and check the length), then the buttons will be shown when `ctrl.userProfile` has a length, right? I want the buttons to be shown depending on what `ctrl.userProfile.watching` is, not just when `ctrl.userProfile` has a length.

Comment: @user2719875 Right. In my example the `ready` flag goes false when a new fetch is started. Your user can see the old profile but the `Follow` or `Unfollow` buttons disappear, preventing erroneous following or unfollowing of the new user profile.

Comment: @georgeawg I think a ready flag is a good approach however, I wouldn't do it as a property of the same object as the response. You're polluting that data model. I would move it out of that object.